# Exception Handling in Java to have Java best practices

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, illegalargumentexception

I have a Java method like below:

```
private boolean getBooleanProperty(String property, String defaultValue) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            result = Boolean.parseBoolean(properties.getProperty(property, defaultValue));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | NullPointerException e) {
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I know that the way I am handling the exceptions in above method is not correct and looking for the way to have those more aligned with the Java standards and best practices.

Similarly for the method below:

```
public void getStatusAndAnnotation(ITestResult result) { 
        try {
            HashMap<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            Method method = result.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod();
            TestInfo annotation = method.getAnnotation(TestInfo.class);
            try {
                //add id removing the first character of the annotation (e.g. for C12034, send 12034)
                if(annotation!=null) {
                    map.put("id",annotation.id().substring(1));
                }

            }catch (NullPointerException e){ 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
                map.put("result", 1);
            } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
                map.put("result", 9);
            } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
                map.put("result", 10);
            }
            if (annotation != null) {
                if(annotation.trDeploy() && !map.get("id").equals(null) && !map.get("id").toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    ApiIntegration.addTestResult(map);
                }
                else System.out.println("Deploying result was canceled, because test has annotation \"trDeploy: false\" or \"id\" has no value");
            }

        } catch (SecurityException | IOException
                | ApiException | NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

How do I handle these different exceptions to align with the best practices?

Comment: You shouldn't catch runtime exceptions such as NullPointerException

Comment: You should remove the two first exception Just use if control and the Last Catch

Comment: Never catch NullPointerException.  It indicates a programmer error—one you should be fixing, not bypassing or suppressing.

Comment: Can someone give me a detailed example? How should i fix exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I typically do is let the compiler/IDE tell me what exceptions I need to catch unless you want to catch an exception for a specific reason. That way, I can code without catching unnecessary exceptions and my code is cleaner.

These type of Exceptions are called [Checked Exceptions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Checked_Exceptions)

> "In the Java class hierarchy, an exception is a checked exception if
>   it inherits from java.lang.Exception, but not from
>   java.lang.RuntimeException. All the application or business logic
>   exceptions should be checked exceptions."

**Example**:

```
try
{
   // open a file (Compiler will force to either catch or throw)
}
catch (IOException ioe)
{
   ioe.printStackTrace();

   // need to make a decision on what to do here
   // log it, wrap it in a RuntimeException, etc.
}
```

As for [Unchecked Exceptions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Unchecked_Exceptions)

> "Unchecked, uncaught or runtime exceptions are exceptions that can be
>   thrown without being caught or declared"

**Example**:

```
String x = null;

// this will throw a NullPointerException
// However, you don't need to catch it as stated in some the comments
x.toString();
```

What you should do is **prevent** it

```
if (x == null)
{
   x = "some default value"; // prevent the exception from happening.
}
x.toString();
```

Does this mean you should never catch a **RuntimeException**

No, of course not. It depends on the scenario.

**Take this example**:

```
String number = "12345";

// You don't know if number is a valid integer until you parse it
// If the string is not a valid number, then this code will 
// throw an Exception
int i = Integer.parseInt(number);
```

Instead you can catch a NumberFormatException. Again, this is a form of **prevention**.

```
int i = 0; // some default
try
{
   i = Integer.parseInt(number);
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
{
   // Good practice to log this, but the default int is fine.
}
```

**Some Best Practices**

- Do not catch exceptions unless the compiler forces you to.
- If you are catching a checked exception, then log it. You can also wrap it in a RuntimeException if you want it to percolate up the call stack.
- If you want to catch a RuntimeException, then do so with a purpose (i.e. you can set a default and prevent the error all together.)
- Don't have a chain of methods all throwing a checked Exception up the stack trace. This is very messing and forces all calling methods to either catch or throw the checked exception.
- Catching a RuntimeException just to log it really doesn't have much of a purpose. Unless you are logging it in a catch all location.

**Catch-All Example**:

```
try
{
   // entry point to application
}
catch (Throwable t)
{
   // let all exceptions come here to log them
}
```